# aws cloudformation - Value at 'content.s3Bucket' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I was going to access the s3 bucket for the zip file.
When I use below code, it can access the bucket because it uses root directory of the bucket.

"S3Bucket": {
"Ref": "HandlerCodeS3Bucket"
},

when I want to access the layers folder of same bucket, I use HandlerCodeS3BucketLayer parameters.
But it shows below error.

```
1 validation error detected: Value 'admin-sourcecode/layers' at 'content.s3Bucket' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[0-9A-Za-z\.\-_]*(?<!\.)$ (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: xxx)
```

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    
    "Parameters": {
      "HandlerCodeS3Bucket": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "admin-sourcecode"
      },
      "HandlerCodeS3BucketLayer": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "admin-sourcecode/layers"
      }
    },
    "Resources": {
      "MyLayer": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion",
        "Properties": {
            "CompatibleRuntimes": [
                "nodejs12.x"
            ],
            "Content": {
                "S3Bucket": {
                  "Ref": "HandlerCodeS3BucketLayer"
                },
                "S3Key": "imageUploadLayer.zip"
            },
            "Description": "My layer",
            "LayerName": "imageLayer",
            "LicenseInfo": "MIT"
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Put it through a yaml validator first, and in a good editor like vscode. Check there's no red squiggly underlines in the yaml..Next check the IAM role assigned has the rights? Or is it saying your condition doesn't satisfy: `Default": "admin-sourcecode/layers"`, so does it work with a wild card `*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bucket name **can't** contain slashes:

```
admin-sourcecode/layers
```

Maybe in your code it should be:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    
    "Parameters": {
      "HandlerCodeS3Bucket": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "admin-sourcecode"
      },
      "HandlerCodeS3BucketLayer": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "admin-sourcecode"
      }
    },
    "Resources": {
      "MyLayer": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion",
        "Properties": {
            "CompatibleRuntimes": [
                "nodejs12.x"
            ],
            "Content": {
                "S3Bucket": {
                  "Ref": "HandlerCodeS3BucketLayer"
                },
                "S3Key": "layers/imageUploadLayer.zip"
            },
            "Description": "My layer",
            "LayerName": "imageLayer",
            "LicenseInfo": "MIT"
        }
    }
   }
  }
```